# How to get the length of http response python scapy

Tags: python, http, tcp, scapy

So I am writing a python scapy script that will first just complete a 3 way handshake, send an http get, and then close the connection.

This is the code so far:

```
!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

getStr = 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n'

#Send SYN
syn = IP(src="31.31.31.10",dst='31.31.31.17') /         TCP(dport=80,sport=RandShort(),flags='S')
syn_ack = sr1(syn)`

#Send GET w/ ACK of server's SA
get1 = (IP(src="31.31.31.10",dst="31.31.31.17")/TCP(dport=80, sport=syn_ack[TCP].dport,seq=syn_ack[TCP].ack, ack=syn_ack[TCP].seq + 1, flags='PA')/getStr)
send (get1)

pkts = sniff(count=1,filter="host 31.31.31.17 and port 80",prn=lambda x:x.summary())
print pkts.sprintf("%TCP.len%") #Will this work? I am getting an issue here

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sprintf'
```

Basically I just want to extract the len of data from the PA, which is the http response, so I can correctly generate the following sequence number to ACK the http response.

I have also tried: ans,uns=sr(get1) But I could not find a good way to get the length from this either.

I have also tried: print len(pkts.getlayer(TCP)) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getlayer'

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected since you have used a plural, `pkts` is a `PacketList` and not a `Packet`.

You can use:

```
for p in pkts:
    if TCP in p:
        print len(p[TCP].payload)
```

You can add `and not isinstance(p[TCP].payload, NoPayload)` if you want to skip packets with no data.

You can also modify the BPF filter so that it reads: `"host 31.31.31.17 and tcp port 80"` (add `tcp`).

Comment: This will compile but I don't get a length, I get a ???

Here is the output:

Begin emission:
.........Finished to send 1 packets.
.*
Received 11 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
.
Sent 1 packets.
Ether / IP / TCP 31.31.31.17:http > 31.31.31.10:20810 PA / Raw
??

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I have updated by answer, should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Scapy overloads a lot of internal attributes in it's base class, one of the being `__len__`. Building on @Pierre's answer I would think that

```
for p in pkts:
    print len(p)
```

if you need only for the length of the TCP packet and onward only, try:

```
for p in pkts:
    print len(p[TCP])
```

have a look in the Scapy source at scapy/packet.py to figure you what else is overloaded by `class Packet`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `packet[TCP].payload` alone, it includes the padding and will give you an incorrect length if the packet has padding.

Instead, you can use:

```
tcp_payload_len = len(pkt[TCP].payload)
if pkt.haslayer(Padding):
  tcp_payload_len -= len(pkt[Padding])
```

see: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/707